# Swipe a container (message box like telegram) left in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, drag-and-drop, messagebox

I'm trying to implement left dragging to a specific container or actually a message box like the one in **Telegram** where you can swipe the message left to reply to it.

[Telegram message dragging when reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUKcH.jpg)

I tried the **Flutter Dismissible Widget** but firstly it destroys the widget or remove it and secondly couldn't find a way to drag it to the center only.

What I want is the same technique in **Telegram** to implement it on Flutter

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [swipeable](https://pub.dev/packages/swipeable) package, it allows you to wrap a widget with some threshold and a few callbacks that you can react, onSwipeLeft or onSwipeRight for this case. Then you save the selected message and render the message box on top of the message bar.